# How to query an one-to-many relationship in ndb?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

```
class User(UserMixin, ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    password_hash = ndb.TextProperty(required = True)

class Record(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
    notes = ndb.TextProperty()
```

In Django and I believe also the classic GAE-db you would query the records belonging to the user like this:

```
user = "get user instance"
user.record_set.all()
```

but in ndb, this approach throws an error.  [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries) doesn't shed a light on this.

Any idea how I would achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googeling for over an hour, I finally stumbled upon this [cheatsheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/mobilebasic). It compares the features of classic db vs ndb very nicely.

According to the cheat-sheet the concept of `collection_set` is no longer supported in ndb, which is a shame. I found it much more logical.

Now you have to do this instead:

```
records = Record.query(Record.user == user.key)
```